# bxslider slide align center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I'am trying to make slider which is view align center. And the center slide should be in center of the red line(div)

This is what I tried. https://fiddle.jshell.net/4xgpgng1/1/

```
<style>
div.bxslider { margin:0 50%; text-align:center; }
.slide{  width: initial !important; margin: 0px 20px ;   }
.slide img { width: 130px;  }
</style>


<div style="position:absolute; width:140px; height:100px; border:1px solid red; margin:0 0 0 -70px; top:0;left:50%;z-index:2"></div>

<div class="bxslider">
    <div class="slide a1"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/112233/ffffff?text=FooBar1" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/ee5678/ffffff?text=FooBar2" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/435ab6/ffffff?text=FooBar3" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/11cc22/ffffff?text=FooBar4" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/ffa500/ffffff?text=FooBar5" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/cc44ff/ffffff?text=FooBar6" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/112233/ffffff?text=FooBar1" /></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x680/ee5678/ffffff?text=FooBar2" /></div>  
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 130,
    minSlides: 12,
    maxSlides: 12,
    moveSlides: 1,
    pager: false,
    auto: false
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```css
.slide img {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% + 20px);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wv168r6f/).

Answer (score 0):

This may help somebody. I've solved similar problem by setting width to parent container

```
.sliderWrapper {
  max-width: 640px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="img-container">
 <div class="imgGallery">
  <div><img src="assets/img/Ocean.jpg" title="Funky roots"></div>
  <div><img src="assets/img/Cliff.png" title="The long and winding road"></div>
  <div><img src="assets/img/Tumpak-sewu.jpg" title="Happy trees"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.img-container div {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}
```

**TS code:**

```
$('.imgGallery').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: false,
  slideWidth: 500,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bx-wrapper {
      max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Some additional context for how your answer adds value to others already here or approaches the problem differently would help future visitors to the site.